# Whenever I open the Mac Terminal it shows "no such files or directory"

Tags: terminal, mac, macos, bash

Whenever I open my Mac Terminal something goes wrong. I am getting:

> -bash: USERNAME: No such file or directory

This issue started to happen suddenly. I don't have any clue why it is happening.

Comment: Have You checked `~/.bash_profile` file?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek how to open that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you open terminal some scripts are automatically called.

Programs (and users) add different commands to those files to set up their environment.

In default OS X configuration you are running a Bash shell which might run the following scripts:

- `~/.bash_profile` (most probable)
- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/bashrc`
- other can also be included from the above

You need to check (display for example with command `cat ~/.bash_profile`) each of them and search for the string `USERNAME` that is in the error message.

The next step depends solely on the content of the file. You might remove the offending lines or (safer) comment them out (putting `#` in front of the line).